# How to remove "via" and server name when sending mails with PHP?

Tags: php, email

When I send a mail with PHP the destinatary gets a header like this one:

```
   noreply@justwalk.it **via** de p3nlhg147.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
```

I want to remove the "via" part. Most automated mails from websites don't have the "via" so it's certainly possible to remove it.

How do they do it?

Comment: you cant, it's the mail server(s) not php.

Comment: Yes, you can. Please take a look below answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can get rid the "via" part. Here's the details:

```
1) SPF and DKIM
```

Firstly, you would need to set an [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record for the domain you are sending emails from and enable [DKIM](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/EmailAuthentication#Set%20up%20DKIM) as well. These are primarily for identifying your messages against spam.

```
2) "From: anything@yourdomain.com"
```

Secondly, make sure you are setting the “From: ” header to be an email address on the domain you are sending messages from. Don’t pretend to be someone else. Use “From: someone@abc.com” if you are sending the messages from abc.com, rather than anything else, such as blah@def.com, or yours@gmail.com, or whatever. If you want the recipient to reply to your Gmail email instead of your domain email, use the “Reply-To: ” header. “From: ” must always be the domain email that you are sending the email from.

```
3) "Return-Path: return@yourdomain.com"
```

Thirdly and most importantly, set the “Return-Path: ” header to be the same domain as that of the “From: ” header. Use the 5th parameter of the mail() function for this:

```
mail('recipient@example.com', 'Subject', "Message Body", $headers, '-freturn@yourdomain.com')
```

So the Return-Path of this message would be “return@yourdomain.com” (the email address immediately following the -f switch). The $headers parameter should contain all the necessary message headers. Make sure “From: ” is something@yourdomain.com.

After these steps and measures, Gmail should now completely trust your messages from yourdomain.com. The ‘via‘ field of your messages should be gone and the ‘mailed-by‘ field as well as the ‘signed-by‘ field should be correctly showing up as yourdomain.com.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Would this work if the mail server is different than the site server?

Comment: Thanks, it works like charm... I used only two steps, 2nd and 3rd.. Thanks richard...

Answer (score 8):

I also fetched the same problem. But I have overcome the problem by using the following code:

```
mail('maaaa@abcd.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,'-faaa@abc.com');
```

Make sure that last parameter is -f with the email address.

You can add the

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";<br />
mail('maaaa@abc.com', 'the subject', 'the message body in html format', $headers,'-faaaa@abc.com');
```

for the html message body in email.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably added by your MTA and you didn't say which MTA you are using.

I'd recommend sending the mails not by PHP's `mail()` function but via SMTP, possibly even with SMTP-Auth, using something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

@Mujibur is also right, But I used. But Didn't missed Headers too.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f'.$from_email_address);
```

And its successful to me, Let's check it from your side.

Answer (score 0):

See what Google says about this here: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1311182

All the best!

Comment: Rather than just provide a link you should try explaining the content in this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.