# how to remove the "Via" mail in sending a mail

Tags: php, email, sendmail

i'm using Cpanel in Hostgator and PHP to send the mail. when i use this code i always receive mail via mail as "birkin.websitewelcome.com" . when i send mail through joomla "via" mail id is not added. i don't want to display "birkin.websitewelcome.com" in the mails.

is there any code to be added in mail.php

[image]

mail.php

```
$guest_ip   = $visitor_location['IP'];

$guest_country = $visitor_location['CountryName'];

$guest_city  = $visitor_location['CityName'];

$guest_state = $visitor_location['RegionName'];

$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$subject1=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['subject']);
$messag=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['message']);
$to = "id@mydomain.com";

$subject = 'Mail From Contact Page - Surabi Institutions';

$headers = "From: info@mydomain.org \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To:info@mydomain.org \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<div style="border: 1px solid #292929; margin:0 auto; height:auto;
width:70%;  color:#808080; padding: 0% 10%;">';
$message .= '<h3>Mail From Contact Page</h3>';
$message .= '<strong>Name</strong>:'.$name.'<br>';
$message .= '<strong>Email</strong>:'.$email.'<br>';
$message .= '<strong>Subject</strong>:'.$subject1.'<br>';
$message .= '<strong>Message</strong><br>'.$messag.'<br><br /><br /><br /> </div>';
$message .= '<div style="border-top:1px solid #cacaca; margin-top:50px; height:auto; color:#faa;">';
$message .= '<b>Visitor IP</b> -'.$guest_ip.'<br>';
$message .='<b>Visitor City</b> -'.$guest_city.'<br>';
$message .='</div> ';
$message .= '</body></html>';


if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Thank you. We will be in touch with you very soon.'); window.location='index.php';</script>";
}
else
{
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Mail Sending Failed Please Try Again'); history.back();</script> ";
}
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236312/how-to-remove-via-and-server-name-when-sending-mails-with-php

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

```
$to = ""test@gmail.com;                 
$from = "info@test.com";

$headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// now lets send the email. 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```