# How to remove 'via' email address while sending mails using php

Tags: php, email

I am using the below php mail code to send mails

```
<?php
      $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
      $headers .="From:servername<info@server.com>" . "\r\n";
      @mail("username@gmail.com", "personal", "mail testing", $headers,"-f aaaa@abc.com");
    ?>
```

The mail is sending successfully but getting 'via' address in the mail as `server@gmail.com via servername.secureserver.net`.

How to remove 'via' address from emails using php, i am using windows server platform

Comment: Send them via gmail. Think about it for a minute, if it was possible to remove it that way, you could send emails from any email address and it would not be visible that you're impersonating another individual.

Comment: Using SMTP will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Are you sure that is not the email client doing that to alert the user  of the server sending email from a domain that does not belong to it?

Comment: [`As per this Q&A`](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/Y66dR4ILYfk), *and I quote*: That is something the receiving email program displays, not something you control.  E.g., Gmail displays "via" when the sending domain does not match the sender's address and it is not identified as a trusted sender. 

Adding an SPF record for your domain, identifying GoDaddy as a trusted sender, may remove the "via". [`This answer may help also`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14964547/)