# Cakephp email sending email with "via" near to sender email id

Tags: cakephp

Im fed up with this problem, tried all the things and measures but the problem remains. Whenever im sending an Email using cakephp 2.x im getting a "via" xyzabc.com , near to the sender's email id in email inbox.

Here is my code -

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from('noreply@'.env('SERVER_NAME'));
$Email->replyTo('noreply@'.env('SERVER_NAME'));
$Email->sender('noreply@'.env('SERVER_NAME'));
$Email->to('myemailid@gmail.com');
$Email->subject('Account activation Link');
$username="Katrina";
$link="http://mywebsite.com/users/account_activation/myemailid@gmail.com/jkasjfi3ed34";
$Email->viewVars(array('user_name' => $username,'link'=>$link));
$Email->template("user/new_user_registered");
$Email->emailFormat("html");
$Email->send();
```

Please help with the issue, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Possibly relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236312/how-to-remove-via-and-server-name-when-sending-mails-with-php

Comment: thanx for replying, the real problem is- it is working fine with php mail() function. But going wrong with cakephp code. cannot find the issue.

Comment: Is there is any error message? Is is sending nothing or sending blank html?

Comment: there is no error message..rest everything is fine.

Comment: What is the configuration of CakePHP mailer?