# when i send email using PHP mail function then getting in Form header abc@xyz.com via asd.com

Tags: javascript, php, email, mysqli, phpmailer

I am using PHP mail function for send email. But when I send email I get this in Form Header `" info@aarthlogistic.com via blue.truehostdns.com "`.

This is my code:

```
$from="info <info@aarthlogistic.com>";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
mail('xxxxxp@xxx.com','NoReply', $clent_emailbody,$headers);
```

How to remove my hosting provider domain (`blue.truehostdns.com`) from my emails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236312/how-to-remove-via-and-server-name-when-sending-mails-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHPMailer, it will be much easier to accomplish what you are looking for this way

```
require('PHPMailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
```

With this it should look like :

```
From : Mailer ( from@example.com )
To : Joe User ( joe@example.net ) , ellen@example.com
Object : Here is the subject
------------------------------------------------------
This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>
```

And if you hit reply, it will automatically reply to the mailer

You can find PHPMailer here : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Good advice, but use an [up to date version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and example code.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it has been a while since I did not have to send mail with phpmailer haha

I will edit with the correct informations