# How to remove "via" from email using mail()

Tags: php, email

I have read [How to remove "via" and server name when sending mails with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236312/how-to-remove-via-and-server-name-when-sending-mails-with-php), however, it's not helping in this case.

I want to send an email to `example@gmail.com`, the email will be sent from `example@hotmail.com`, using PHP mail(), however when I do this, it says `via example.prod.ex3.example.net`. How would I remove that, bearing in mind I've tried the above solution? Here's my code.

```
<?php

$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$txt = $_POST['msg'];
$headers = "Return-Path: " . $_POST['from'] . "\r\n" . "From: " . $_POST['from'] . "\r\n" .
"CC: ".$_POST['from'];

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
header('Location: ..');
?>
```

Comment: `From: " . $_POST['from']` < that POST is unknown and it expects an email address. Please go over the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and the form is unknown.

Comment: You should avoid using the mail() function; use an established library such as PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.