# How to remove “via” and server name when sending mails via laravel 5.4 not with php mail function

Tags: smtp, laravel-5.4

I am sending emails using smtp in a laravel 5.4 project.

```
    Mail::send('emails.passwordreset-user', ['token' => $originalToken, 'name' => $dataWithEmail->first_name,'email' => $supportEmail], function($message) use ($dataWithEmail) {

        $message->to($dataWithEmail->email, $dataWithEmail->first_name)->replyTo($dataWithEmail->adminEmail, 'Sender name')
                ->subject('Password Reset');
    });
```

I need to remove "via servername" that appears just after from email address in the email.
I found that we can solve using -f parameter in php mail function. But how to deal the same in laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14964547/9764507. You need to set a SPF and DKIM.

Then, create a `Mailable` for your email and try with `Return-Path` header in `build()` method of `Mailable`:

```php
public function build()
{
    $this->view('emails.passwordreset-user');

    $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
        $message->getHeaders()
                ->addTextHeader('Return-Path', 'return@yourdomain.com');
    });
}
```

More about Mailables here: [Writing Mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#writing-mailables)