# Remove Email Hosting Address When Sending Email - PHP Mail()

Tags: php, email, email-client

I am using PHP mail() functinon to send email from my website.

Email is sent, however on reciver email it shows name@domain.com via [hostingname]

Could any please guide if it is possible to remove via [hostingname], I have attached screenshot of recieved email

[image: screen shot of received email]

I tried to send email using PHP mail() function, email was sent, however, it contained hosting address, i want to remove that

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236312/how-to-remove-via-and-server-name-when-sending-mails-with-php
A similar problem described