# Remove 'via [Domain name]' from sent mail using mail()

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHP mail() function to send email, emails are being sent fine.
Help needed in removing the "via" part form sent mail.

** PHP Code: **

```
        <?php
   
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                
        // look for errors generated 
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                
        // get Form data in variables
                $to = $_POST['reciever_email'];
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $from = $_POST['sender_email'];
                
        // make headers for sent mail 
                $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
                $headers .= "From:" $from "\r\n"; 

        // send email now   
                  $result =  mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
                  
        // show results pass/fail via html
                if($result){
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success mt-3'>Email has been sent successfully</div>";
                }else{
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger mt-3'>Sorry! something went wrong</div>";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

**NOTE:** Email is being sent from shared hosting with via [domain name] written in header, but email from VPS server is not being sent and it shows success message, and no email is received.

I dont want to use PHPMailer library and I have tried appending "From" in Header. But this is not working on VPS server. Shared hosting server is sending email with 'via'.

Comment: Did you research this before you asked ...? [Google: php mail remove via site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mail+remove+via+site%3Astackoverflow.com&sca_esv=568176390) gets plenty of results already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove "via" and server name when sending mails with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236312/how-to-remove-via-and-server-name-when-sending-mails-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

use mail function like this:

```
mail('info@example.com', 'Subject', 'MessageBody', null,'-finfo@mysite.com');
```

Make sure that last parameter is -f with the email address. Also, You can add header like this for send HTML email:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
mail('info@example.com', 'Subject', 'HTMLmessageBody', $headers,'-finfo@mysite.com');
```

Base of my experience, I recommend sending emails by PHPMailer or any similar, stable scripts.